# Group disjoint, non-overlapping, directional, ordered linear intervals given a group length and an between-group length cutoffs

Tags: r, union, intervals

I have a `data.frame` with a set of disjoint, non-overlapping, ordered, directional linear intervals defined by their interval sequence name (`seqname` below), and their `start` and `end` coordinates on them:

```
df <- data.frame(seqname = c("s1","s1","s1","s1","s1","s1","s2","s3"),
                 start = c(50,150,250,350,650,750,300,600),
                 end = c(100,200,300,400,700,800,400,700))
```

In reality these are putative genes parts along the DNA (`seqname`s are chromosomes) and I'm trying to decide if they are part of the same gene or separate genes. The cutoffs are empirical and are based on actual gene lengths and between gene lengths in that genome (specific to that certain type of genes).

I would like to group the intervals (separately for each `seqname`) using two length cutoffs: one that defines the maximum group length (i.e., end coordinate of the last interval in the group minus the start coordinate of the first interval in the group) and the other that defines the minimum length between consecutive groups (between-group length). Meaning that a group of intervals cannot be longer than the maximum group length cutoff and two consecutive groups cannot be separated by less than minimum between-group length cutoff.

Obviously the two constraints can be in conflict - addition of an interval to an existing group which difference between its start coordinate and the end coordinate of the existing group is less than the minimum between-group length cutoff but adding it will result with a group whose length is longer than maximum group cutoff. So in that case the maximum group cutoff constraint can be violated.

For this example the maximum group length cutoff is 300 and the minimum between-group length cutoff is 100 so the result would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% dplyr::mutate(id = c("s1.1","s1.1","s1.1","s1.1","s1.2","s1.2","s2.1","s3.1"))
```

where `id` is the grouping ID.

See that the fourth interval on `s1` is grouped with `s1.1` because although adding it to `s1.1` ends up with `s1.1` being of length 350 > maximum group length cutoff, it is located 50 downstream to the end of `s1.1` (without adding it) which still satisfies that minimum between-group contraint.

Any idea how to implement this in R, perhaps using `intervals` `package` or similar ones?

Comment: Where does the `maximum group length cutoff is 300` constraint come from? Is that intuited from the data, for instance the difference between row 4 end and row 5 end?

Comment: Yes, they are empirical. I edited my question to give more details about that

Comment: Are some of the intervals overlapping in your data? Can we assume they are sorted, e.g. in order of start coordinate?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the 100 minimum between-group length is applied, as it seems many segments are only 50 apart, including row 4 vs. row 3.

Comment: I edited my question adding that the intervals are non-overlapping and ordered.  About the  100 minimum between-group length cutoff, it separates intervals 1-4 and 5-6 to separate groups

Comment: I'm thinking that for each `seqname`, adding maximum group length to each start of each interval except the last, then using the `interval_union` function of the `intervals` `R` package on the `data.frame` converted to a `GenomeIntervals` object of the `genomeIntervals` `R` package will give the groups. And as a post-process step these groups can be merged if the distance between them is less than the  minimum between-group cutoff

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that counts gaps between last end and current start of > 100.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(seqname) %>%
  mutate(gap = start - lag(end, default = 0),
         new_grp = row_number() == 1 | gap > 100,
         group = cumsum(new_grp),
         group_name = paste(seqname, group, sep = ".")) %>%
  ungroup()



## A tibble: 8 x 7
#  seqname start   end   gap new_grp group group_name
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <int> <chr>     
#1 s1         50   100    50 TRUE        1 s1.1      
#2 s1        150   200    50 FALSE       1 s1.1      
#3 s1        250   300    50 FALSE       1 s1.1      
#4 s1        350   400    50 FALSE       1 s1.1      
#5 s1        650   700   250 TRUE        2 s1.2      
#6 s1        750   800    50 FALSE       2 s1.2      
#7 s2        300   400   300 TRUE        1 s2.1      
#8 s3        600   700   600 TRUE        1 s3.1
```